# Web Bluetooth reconnect/auto-connect not work

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-bluetooth

I try  [Google/chrome samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/web-bluetooth) for Web Bluetooth.   It looks like device.gatt.connect() is only work within the promise of navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice().   I follow the sample to save the device and call device.gatt.connect() later and it is wait forever and no return.  I am using Mac OSX 10.13.3 and chrome64 and Android BLE Peripheral Simulator (From Google playstore)

The code segment ...

```
  var bluetoothDevice;
  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
     acceptAllDevices: true})
  .then(device => {
    bluetoothDevice = device;
    bluetoothDevice.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', onDisconnected);
    connect();
    ....
    });
    ....
   });

  function connect() {
  exponentialBackoff(3 /* max retries */, 10 /* seconds delay */,
    function toTry() {
      time('Connecting to Bluetooth Device... ');

      /***** Issue here *****
      bluetoothDevice.gatt.connect() called by neither return nor catch error 
      ***********************/
      return bluetoothDevice.gatt.connect().catch(error => {
        log('Argh! ' + error);
      });
    },
    function success() {
      log('> Bluetooth Device connected. Try disconnect it now.');
    },
    function fail() {
      time('Failed to reconnect.');
    });
   }
```

Anyone can explains how to make reconnecting of bond device work?

Comment: Does https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/automatic-reconnect.html works for you?

Comment: no...  The sample also not work for me.   when I disconnect the device either walk away or disconnect from android or disconnect from web app,  I see the log "Connecting to Bluetooth Device..." and no further response.